# sharepoint site CSS Settings

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint siteActions on the left hand side and My links tab on the right hand side. One is in td tag and other one is on div tag.

I cannot understand the code. Could any one showm me how to update the same. The following is the code in my master Page.

```
<SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
  PrefixHtml="&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;"
  SuffixHtml="&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
  MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;"><CustomTemplate>
  <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
   FeatureScope="Site"
   Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
   GroupId="SiteActions"
   UseShortId="true"
   >
   <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_pagetitle_create%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdescription%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Actionscreate.gif"
    MenuGroupId="100"
    Sequence="100"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/create.aspx"
    PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
    PermissionMode="Any" />
   <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescription%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.gif"
    MenuGroupId="100"
    Sequence="200"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:MSOLayout_ChangeLayoutMode(false);"
    />
   <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Settings"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,settings_pagetitle%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitesettingsdescription%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsSettings.gif"
    MenuGroupId="100"
    Sequence="300"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/settings.aspx"
    PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
    PermissionMode="Any" />
  </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
  </CustomTemplate></SharePoint:SiteActions>


<div class="sharepointLogin">
  <!--Authentication for Authors only-->
   <table summary="site links" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
     <td class="ms-globallinks hide" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 69px">
     <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink1" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
     <td class="ms-globallinks">
     <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
     <td class="ms-globallinks">
     <wssuc:Welcome id="explitLogout" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

How do I put it togather is the same line..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="<ID Menu Item"
    Text="<Text to appear on Menu Item"
    Description="<Descriprion Text>"
    ImageUrl="<<URL Of image to be displayed at left of the menu>>"
    MenuGroupId="<<Menu Group ID to group similar items>>"
    Sequence="<<order in which te menu item should apear in its group>>"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="<<Navigation URL>>"
    PermissionsString=" <<Group name to which the menu item should be visible eg. EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData>>"
    PermissionMode="Any" />
```